# Interest Calculator looping issue Python

Tags: python

beginner here. I've made an interest calculator program to help me with my loans of different sorts. I'm having two issues to finalize my program. Here's the program. I tried looking up the problems but I wasn't sure how to word it so I thought I'd just ask a question in total.

```
x=1
while x==1:
    import math
    loan=input("Enter Loan amount: ")
    rate=input("Enter rate: ")
    if rate.isalpha() or loan.isalpha():
        print("Hey that's not a number!")
        break
    rate=rate.replace("%","")
    loan=float(loan)
    rate=float(rate)*0.01
    amount1y=round(loan*(math.e**(rate*1)),2)
    amount5y=round(loan*(math.e**(rate*5)),2)
    amount10y=round(loan*(math.e**(rate*10)),2)
    monthlypay=round(amount1y-loan,2)
    print("Year 1 without pay: " + str(amount1y))
    print("Year 5 without pay: " + str(amount5y))
    print("Year 10 without pay: " + str(amount10y))
    print("Amount to pay per year: " + str(monthlypay))
    print("Want to do another? Y/N?")
    ans=input('')
    ans=ans.lower()
    y=True
    while y==True:
        if ans=="n" or ans=="no":
            x=0
            break
        elif ans=="y" or ans=="yes":
            y=False
        else:
            print("You gotta tell me Yes or No fam...")
            print("I'll just assume that mean's yes.")
            break
```

My issue is in two locations. First during the

```
if rate.isalpha() or loan.isalpha():
        print("Hey that's not a number!")
        break
```

How do I write this so that instead of it ending the program all together, it instead restarts from the top until they put in a number. Also as a side just for fun and knowledge. Lets say they enter text three times in a row, and at that point it just executes the program how would I go about doing that also?
Finally during this part of the code:

```
 while y==True:
        if ans=="n" or ans=="no":
            x=0
            break
        elif ans=="y" or ans=="yes":
            y=False
        else:
            print("You gotta tell me Yes or No fam...")
            print("I'll just assume that mean's yes.")
            break
```

the else at the end, without that break, will continue printing "You gotta tell me Yes or No fam..." forever. How do I make it so that instead of breaking the while statement, it'll just restart the while statement asking the question again?

Thanks for your help!
P.S. This is python 3.4.2

Comment: use `continue` instead of `break`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On both of your examples, I believe your looking for Python's `continue` [statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue). From the Python Docs:

(emphasis mine)

> continue may only occur syntactically nested in a for or while loop, but not nested in a function or class definition or finally clause within that loop. **It continues with the next cycle of the nearest enclosing loop.**
>   When continue passes control out of a try statement with a finally clause, that finally clause is executed before really starting the next loop cycle.

This basically means it will "restart" your `for/while`-loop.

---

To address your side note of breaking the loop if they get the input wrong after three tries, use a counter variable. increment the counter variable each time the user provides the wrong input, and then check and see if the counter variable is greater than 3. Example:

```
counter = 0
running = True:
while running:
    i = input("Enter number: ")
    if i.isalpha():
        print("Invalid input")
        counter+=1
    if counter >= 3:
        print("Exiting loop")
        break
```

**Unrelated notes:**

- Why not use a boolean value for `x` as well?
- I usually recommend putting any imports at the module level for the structure an readability of one's program.

Comment: _"Don't put that import statement in the while loop. On each iteration, it will import math, which will flood the namespace. I usually recommend putting any imports at the module scope."_ There's no such thing. Every module you import will be recorded in `sys.modules`. This serves two or more purposes. First, avoiding circular imports and second as an optimization. Coding `import mod` in a loop won't necessarily import `mod` module many times. I said not necessarily because as long as `mod` is in `sys.modules`, `mod` won't be imported again as `import` stmt inspects `sys.modules` list first.

Comment: @direprobs Fair enough. I did not fully read into all the implantation details. Will edit to be correct.

Comment: Thank you guys! This really helped out and I can say my program works as intended and without any bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You make an infinite loop, that you `break` out of when all is well. Simplified:

```
while True:
    x_as_string = input("Value")
    try:
         x = float(x_as_string)
    except ValueError:
         print("I can't convert", x_as_string)
    else:
         break
```

It is easier to ask forgiveness than permission: You try to convert. If conversion fails you print a notice and continue looping `else` you `break` out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is straightforward. You have to use [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) or [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) wisely. These are called control flow statements. They control the normal flow of execution of your program. So `continue` will jump to the top-most line in your loop and `break` will simply jump *out* of your loop completely, be it a `for` or `while` loop.

Going back to your code:

> How do I write this so that instead of it ending the program all together, it instead restarts from the top until they put in a number.

```
if rate.isalpha() or loan.isalpha():
    print("Hey that's not a number!")
    continue
```

This way, you jump back (you continue) in your loop to the first line:  `import math`. Doing imports inside a loop isn't useful this way the import statement is useless as your imported module is already in `sys.modules` list as such the `import` statement won't bother to import it; if you're using `reload` from `imp` in 3.X or available in `__builtin__` in Python 2.x, then this might sound more reasonable here.

*Ditto:*

```
if ans=="n" or ans=="no":
    x=0
    break
elif ans=="y" or ans=="yes":
        continue
else:
    print("You gotta tell me Yes or No fam...")
    print("I'll just assume that mean's yes.")
    continue
```

To state this snippet in English: if `ans` is equal to `"n"` or `"no"` then break the loop; else if `ans` is equal to `"y"` or `"yes"` then continue. If nothing of that happened, then (`else`) `continue`. The nested `while` loop isn't needed.

> Lets say they enter text three times in a row, and at that point it just executes the program how would I go about doing that also?

Not sure if I understood your question, you can take input three times in different ways:

```
for line in range(3):
    in = input("Enter text for lineno", line)
    ...do something...
```

Comment: I don't believe he wanted to take input three times. most likely he wanted to break his loop, or "execute the program".